# How to get an explanation for an inconsistency using the owlexplanation project

Tags: java, owl, consistency, reasoning

I have a question regarding the owlexplanation project by Matthew Horridge on GitHub.

In the README file there is the following code :

```java
import org.semanticweb.owl.explanation.api.*;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.*;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.reasoner.OWLReasonerFactory;

OWLReasonerFactory rf = ; // Get hold of a reasoner factory
OWLOntology ont = ; // Reference to an OWLOntology

// Create the explanation generator factory which uses reasoners provided by the specified
// reasoner factory
ExplanationGeneratorFactory<OWLAxiom> genFac = ExplanationManager.createExplanationGeneratorFactory(rf);

// Now create the actual explanation generator for our ontology
ExplanationGenerator<OWLAxiom> gen = genFac.createExplanationGenerator(ont);

// Ask for explanations for some entailment
OWLAxiom entailment ; // Get a reference to the axiom that represents the entailment that we want explanation for

// Get our explanations.  Ask for a maximum of 5.
Set<Explanation<OWLAxiom>> expl = gen.getExplanations(entailment, 5);
```

Please could somebody explain what exactly is the type of the parameter `entailment`? I do not quite understand about what thing we get explanations.
I am searching for code that gives me explanations when my ontology is inconsistent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `entailment` parameter is the axiom for which you are trying to determine how the entailment happened.

For explaining an inconsistency, you can follow the suggestion in the README to use a different factory. I've written an example that uses version 1.1.2 of `OWLExplanation` and version 1.2.1 of JFact (I needed a reasoner to test this; any reasoner will do).

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Set;
import org.semanticweb.owl.explanation.api.Explanation;
import org.semanticweb.owl.explanation.api.ExplanationGenerator;
import org.semanticweb.owl.explanation.impl.blackbox.checker.InconsistentOntologyExplanationGeneratorFactory;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.apibinding.OWLManager;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.model.*;
import org.semanticweb.owlapi.reasoner.OWLReasonerFactory;
import uk.ac.manchester.cs.jfact.JFactFactory;
public class TestExplanation {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    OWLReasonerFactory rf = new JFactFactory();
    OWLOntology ont = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager().createOntology();
    OWLOntologyManager m = ont.getOWLOntologyManager();
    OWLDataFactory df = m.getOWLDataFactory();
    OWLClass class1 = df.getOWLClass(IRI.create("urn:test:class1"));
    OWLClass class2 = df.getOWLClass(IRI.create("urn:test:class2"));
    OWLIndividual i = df.getOWLNamedIndividual(IRI.create("urn:test:i"));
    // create an inconsistent ontology by declaring an individual member of two disjoint classes
    m.addAxiom(ont, df.getOWLDisjointClassesAxiom(class1, class2));
    m.addAxiom(ont, df.getOWLClassAssertionAxiom(class1, i));
    m.addAxiom(ont, df.getOWLClassAssertionAxiom(class2, i));
    // create the explanation generator
    ExplanationGenerator<OWLAxiom> explainInconsistency = new InconsistentOntologyExplanationGeneratorFactory(rf,
        1000L).createExplanationGenerator(ont);
    // Ask for an explanation of `Thing subclass of Nothing` - this axiom is entailed in any inconsistent ontology
    Set<Explanation<OWLAxiom>> explanations = explainInconsistency.getExplanations(df.getOWLSubClassOfAxiom(df
        .getOWLThing(), df.getOWLNothing()));
    System.out.println("TestExplanation.main() " + explanations);
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems what exactly i need. I downloaded OWLExplanation and JFact and everything works ok but i get an error "type ExplanationGenerator does not take parameters". Have you any idea why?

Comment: Which version are you using? Make sure you don't have multiple versions in the classpath

Comment: Could you please tell me when you run the example above, your project had only the libraries 1.1.2 of OWLExplanation and version 1.2.1 of JFact ?

Comment: Yes, and their maven dependencies - owlapi 3.5 I believe

Comment: I have added just the following libraries: jfact-1.2.1, owlapi-distribution-3.5.0, owlexplanation-1.1.2, telemetry-1.0.0. And i get the error message "typeExplanationGenerator does not take parameters". I would be really grateful if you have any idea why i get this error. I tried to adapt the "InconsistentOntologyExplanationGeneratorFactory" to the code of the README file but still i get error for that class.

Comment: Make sure the import for ExplanationGenerator is org.semanticweb.owl.explanation.api.ExplanationGenerator. There is a class of the same name in OWLAPI but you don't want to use it.

Answer (score 2):

The Maven dependency shown at https://github.com/matthewhorridge/owlexplanation does not seem to currently exist. Is there an accurate Maven entry available?

Here is what the above page says to use but can't be found:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapitools</groupId>
    <artifactId>owlexplanation</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```